# Web site Hosting Issue: Redirecting to localhost

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7, web, web-hosting

I have created my website to work inside the Server Machine as http:// localhost: 9005 or http:// 216.94.45.84: 9005. Now i am having a site mysite.com. I am using IIS7. I have added created a new Website and modified the binding such that there are two bindings now

They are 
IP Address : Unassigned Port:9005 HostName: -
IP Address : Unassigned Port:80 HostName: mysite.com

So after configuring this when i call the website, mysite.com is resolving and it is redirecting to http:// localhost: 9005. So the site stop working.
Please help me to make my web site working.

My Configurations
Windows 7, PHP, IIS7.

Comment: what is mysite.com's script... wordpress for instance autoredirects clients to a domain defined in it's settings

Comment: Where can we find the settings?

Comment: if it is wordpress the settings are in wp-config.php file and wp_options table in sql

Comment: It is not a word press site. It is OpenX Site. A free advertisement producing site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the config file available for OpenX (localhost.conf.php) in Var folder to the actual website name (Now it may be pointing to local host). So Simple right?

Answer (score 1):

See if you modified your scripts settings according to this tips for moving the OpenX on a new domain: http://www.openxtips.com/2009/06/tip-17-moving-openx/